# Alternar Jpanels dentro de um único JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Em um código Java, possuo um Jframe e dentro deste JFrame possuo um contentPane (Jpanel). Tenho várias telas em formato JPanel, quero trocar esses JPanels ao clicar em um botão que está acoplado dentro de cada um Jpanel. Ao clicar nesse botão, o contentPane será modificado usando e exibindo outra tela Jpanel.

Comment: Olá user4611, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Para que possamos ajudá-lo de maneira mais objetiva, por favor atualize sua questão com um exemplo de código breve e auto-contido. Deixe claro o que você já tentou e onde está tendo problemas; por exemplo, no seu caso, um código com a `JFrame` e o evento que deve trocar o `contentPane` instanciando `JPanel` externos. Sem saber o que você já fez e onde estão suas dificuldades fica muito difícil te ajudar, bem como ajudar indiretamente outros usuários que venham a ter o mesmo problema que você.

Comment: Poderia postar o código do seu `JFrame`? Para que eu possa criar um `ActionListener` que faça o que você pediu, para você usar em seu Botão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abaixo do seu `getContentPane()` coloque um elemento do tipo `JPanel` e defina seu tipo para `CardLayout`, como na figura abaixo:

[image: cards]

Seu código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
private void initialize() {
    frmPrinc = new JFrame(); //variável de instancia

    ... //set size, bounds, title, etc

    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout()); //variável de instancia
    frmPrinc.getContentPane().add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Crie um `JPanel` para cada tela que você deseja, e os coloque dentro do `cards`. No meu caso, eu preferi criar vários métodos para criar cada tela, mas você pode fazer também de um jeito certo porém diferente do meu. Meu código ficou assim:

```
private void telaInicial() {
    telaInicial = new JPanel(); //variável de instancia
    telaInicial.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cards.add(telaInicial, "inicial"); //"inicial" é a chave a ser usada para chamar o objeto "telaInicial"

    ... //adiciona todos os elementos necessários no JPanel telaInicial
}
```

O método `add` é sobrecarregado, e você possui diversas opções de usá-lo, eu optei por usar uma String para referenciar o objeto `telaInicial`, mas você poderia também usar um inteiro.

Veja: [Container (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)

Crie quantas telas desejar, para trocar de uma tela para outra faça assim:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
cl.show(cards, "inicial"); //mudará para a tela inicial
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SeuFrame extends JFrame {

  private JPanel panel1;
  private JPanel panel2;
  private JButton botao1;
  private JButton botao2;

  public SeuFrame() {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    botao1 = new JButton( "Trocar para panel2" );
    botao1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 30 ) );

    botao2 = new JButton( "Trocar para panel1" );
    botao2.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 30 ) );

    panel1.add( botao1 );
    panel2.add( botao2 );

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        JPanel panelTrocar = null;
        if ( e.getSource() == botao1 ) {
          panelTrocar = panel2;
        }
        else {
          panelTrocar = panel1;
        }
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add( panelTrocar );
        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }
    };

    botao1.addActionListener( actionListener );
    botao2.addActionListener( actionListener );

    getContentPane().add( panel1 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Layout CardLayout serve exatamente para isso. Podes utilizá-lo para gerir o JPanel que pretendes ter ativo (visível).

Podes consultar um exemplo de funcionamento em:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html