# Criar validação de dados e sequencia de páginas

Tags: java, swing

Estou iniciando no Java e quero fazer uma tela onde a pessoa cadastre o login e a senha, o sistema armazena os dados e em seguida, em uma nova janela é pedido para que insira o usuário e senha, eu fiz a parte da validação e do cadastrado dos dados na mesma página, pois não domino os `JFrames`.

Como faço para separar as coisas, criar, por exemplo, uma pagina e em seguida a mesma fechar e abrir uma nova? Não sei onde posso fechar o código e abrir um novo, por exemplo.

Segue o código atual, estou trabalhando com Eclipse.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 


public class Exemplo1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 

JButton entrar; 
JTextField cxnome; 
JTextField cxsenha; 
JLabel rotulo; 

JTextField cxvarnome; //variavel de senha a ser inserida
JTextField cxvarsenha; //variavel de senha a ser inserida

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento){ 
String nome, senha, suasenha, seunome; 
nome = cxnome.getText(); 
senha = cxsenha.getText(); 
seunome = cxvarnome.getText(); 
suasenha = cxvarsenha.getText(); 



//metodo da interface ActionListener 
//como o tipo String não é um tipo primitivo, e sim 
//um tipo referencial, sua comparação não pode ser == 
if (evento.getSource()== entrar && nome.equals(seunome)&& senha.equals(suasenha)){

    rotulo.setText("CORRETO");
    dispose();


}
else{
    rotulo.setText("FALHO");
}
}


public static void main(String[] args){ 
    //instanciando objeto 
    Exemplo1 janela = new Exemplo1(); 
    janela.setVisible(true); 
    janela.setTitle("login"); 
    janela.setSize(200,200); 
    janela.setLocation(400,300); 


    } 

//construtor 
public Exemplo1(){ 
//gride para os objetos 
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1)); 

cxvarnome = new JTextField();//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(cxvarnome);//coloca... no grid 

cxvarsenha = new JTextField();//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(cxvarsenha);//coloca... no grid 

cxnome = new JTextField();//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(cxnome);//coloca... no grid 

cxsenha = new JTextField();//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(cxsenha);//coloc... no grid 


entrar = new JButton("OK");//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(entrar);//coloca... no grid 
entrar.addActionListener(this);//add evento ao clicar 

rotulo = new JLabel();//instanciando 
getContentPane().add(rotulo);//coloca... no grid 
rotulo.setOpaque(true);//tornando opaco 
rotulo.setBackground(Color.orange); 



} 

}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta, mas acho que você poderia dar uma olhada nessa pergunta aqui: [Alternar Jpanels dentro de um único JFrame](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4076/3117), talvez ajude (ou talvez não).

Answer (score 4):

Utilize [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) que permite trabalhar com vários `JPanel` dentro de um `Container`. Com esse layout você consegue facilmente controlar o fluxo dos painéis usando métodos para alterná-los:

```
first(C)    // Alterna para o primeiro painel adicionado no container (C).
last(C)     // Alterna para o último painel inserido no container (C).
next(C)     // Muda para o painel seguinte em (C).
previous(C) // Muda para o painel anterior em (C).
show(C, N)  // Alterna para o painel com nome (N) dentro do container (C).
```

Isso evitaria criar uma aplicação com vários `JDialog` e/ou `JFrame`.

_

No seu código você está inserindo todos os componentes diretamente no `JFrame`. Uma melhoria a ser feita é separar as duas *views* (Registro e Login) que você quer em `JPanel` diferentes.

```
// Painel de criação do usuário
JPanel registerView = new JPanel();

// Painel de login
JPanel loginView = new JPanel();
```

Para evitar adicionar tudo direto no `JFrame`, pode ser criado um painel "raiz" onde tudo acontecerá dentro dele (e ele terá o `CardLayout` como layout).

```
/* 
 * É importante armazenar em uma variável para podermos controlar o fluxo
 * dentro do JPanel através dos métodos listados no início dessa resposta.
 */
CardLayout card = new CardLayout();

// JPanel onde serão inseridos os JPanels
JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();
rootPanel.setLayout(card); // definindo o layout
```

Por fim, basta adicionar os painéis de registro e login dentro do `rootPanel`. Aqui, a forma de adicionar é um pouco diferente do simples `jframe.add(jpanel)`, além do componente que queremos adicionar, precisamos também passar um nome único para que possamos identificá-lo.

```
//Inserindo os painéis de Registro e Login,
rootPanel.add(registerView, "register");
rootPanel.add(loginView, "login");

// Painel que será exibido primeiro
card.show(rootPanel, "register"); // mostrará o painel com nome "register"
```

---

#### Código de teste

```
//Window.java

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window(String title){
        super(title);
        init();
    }

    // Inicializa os componentes
    public void init(){
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Painel de criação do usuário
        JPanel registerView = new JPanel();
        registerView.setLayout(null);

        // Botão que avançará para o próximo painel.
        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Me Registrei! Próximo Painel");
        btnNext.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 35);
        registerView.add(btnNext);

        // Painel de login
        JPanel loginView = new JPanel();
        loginView.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblLoginPanel = new JLabel("Esse é o painel de login");
        lblLoginPanel.setBounds(70, 100, 150, 35);
        loginView.add(lblLoginPanel);

        CardLayout card = new CardLayout();

        // JPanel onde serão inseridos os JPanels
        JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.setLayout(card); // definindo o layout
        getContentPane().add(rootPanel);

        // Inserindo os painéis de Registro e Login,
        rootPanel.add(registerView, "register");
        rootPanel.add(loginView, "login");

        card.show(rootPanel, "register"); // mostrará o painel de registro

        // Quando clicado...
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                card.next(rootPanel); // mostra o próximo JPanel dentro do container
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-

```
//Main.java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      new Window("StackOverflow").setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

---

#### Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu código, você pode fazer com que o painel seja avançado quando o usuário clicar, por exemplo, em um botão de conclusão de registro após preencher os campos requeridos. A questão de validar o usuário aparentemente já está implementada no seu código.