# Fechar todas as jframes abertas ao abrir uma nova

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Como posso fechar todas as jframes abertas no meu projeto quando executo uma ação que me abre outra jframe?

Tenho um sistema de login e quando necessário, eu invoco outra frame para definir uma password. Após definir a password eu faço o dispose() a essa jframe e inicio a nova jframe, mas gostava que a jframe de login também fechasse.

Se calhar uma solução mais viável seria chamar um jDialog para definir essa password, mas eu não me sinto à vontade no que toca a jDialogs e por isso é que tou a invocar uma nova jframe.

Alguma sugestão?

**EDIT:**

Crio a '`JFrame Form`' da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois na parte do design o nome da Frame não sei qual é porque só tem isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como é que posso setar essa frame se eu não sei o nome dela ?

Comment: Essa tua edição ainda tem a ver com o mesmo problema?

Comment: Sim, foi uma edição feita a pedido do @joaoNeto para ver se consegue ajudar. Ainda não consegui resolver esta questão

Comment: É exatamente o que disseste no primeiro post. Sendo assim terei de passar a frame por parâmetero. Mas sendo assim tenho de por o parâmetero no construtor? PlataformaLogin(JFrame frame) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que este é o código que precisa:

```
System.gc();  
for (Window window : Window.getWindows()} {  
    window.dispose();  
    // por vezes pode ser melhor usar setVisivel(false);
}
```

**Atenção:**
Este código fecha todos os frames.
Se alguma das suas `frames` tiver a configuração de `setDefaultCloseOperation` como `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` o programa vai encerrar, logo deve de alterar para HIDE_ON_CLOSE

Tens também outra opção:

Se tens a certeza de qual o caminho que o user segui para chegar ao frame que está podes fazer assim:

estrutura:

PainelPrinciapl --> PainelLogin --> PainelAlterarPass

painel principal chama o frame de login:
(leva como parâmetro a referencia do painel principal)

```
login(PainelPrincipal);
```

No construtor do login recebes:

```
public login(JFrame PainelPrincipal){ ... }
```

Se precisas de alterar a password, no login chama o frame alterar password que leva como parametro o `PainelPrincipal` e o  `PainelLogin`:

```
alterarPass(PainelPrincipal, PainelLogin);
```

Na classe do `alterarPass` no construtor recebes assim:

```
  public alterarPass(Jframe PainelPrincipal, Jframe PainelLogin){
      ...
 }
 //depois fazes o dispose destes dois frames onde precisares
  PainelPrincipal.dispose();
  PainelLogin.dispose();
```

**Mas** imagina que ele dutrante este caminho abriu outra frame, essa continuará aberta, por isso é que digo que a primeira abordagem é melhor...

Comment: Mas nesse código onde referencio a frame do login ?

Comment: Este código serve para fechares todas as frames, nao uma em especifico, para uma em especifico vou publicar agora...

Comment: Amigo, esse código chega, porque eu preciso de fechar todas e logo de seguida abrir outra. Está funcional :D Muito Obrigado mais uma vez !!!

Comment: Ainda bem que funcionou, contudo postei as duas formas que conheço ;)

Comment: @HugoMachado só para te dar conhecimento, olha esta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44265/13237 uma solução bem interessante para não teres de andares a saltar de frame em frame ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão é apenas setar a visbilidade da JFrame como false.

```
jframeLogin.setVisible(false);
```

E quando quiser que a mesma apareça novamente:

```
jframeLogin.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Mas como é que eu sei o nome da frame de login? É que eu quero fechá-la ou pô-la invisível ao clicar num botão de outra jframe. Quando abro o "design" da jframe de login lá só diz JFrame

Comment: Em algum lugar você declarou esse frame certo? Ai é só você colocar evento do botap do outro frame o setVisible, no caso, tu tera que passar o frame como parametro para o outro, p que dentro do outro tu possa manipula-lo, ficou meio dificil se entender, mais tarde eu posto um exemplo, agora to no cel. Valeu

Comment: Você ta usando código mesmo ou alguma framework para criar as janelas? Tipo o windowbuilder?

Comment: Só estou a usar classes do tipo 'JFrame Form' ! Eu quando invoco uma nova frame abre-me por cima ou em cima da frame de login. Nessa nova frame ao clicar no botão 'ok' quero abrir uma terceira frame, e fechar a frame de login

Comment: Edita a pergunta com seu código que fica melhor.

Comment: Mas o meu código não o vai ajudar em nada, visto que eu não faço criação de frames pelo código, ex: JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame"); É simplesmente ao criar a classe que cria, mas eu vou por no código a minha dúvida mais especificada